# pandas products analysis getting pairs according to purchases

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

Here's an example of my dataframe:

```
df.head(10) 

 , customer_id  order_id,        product,         purchased_at
 0,   2,        2000,               B,         2021-05-01 21:51:13
 1,   1,        1996,               A,         2021-04-06 13:02:37
 2,   1,        2540,               B,         2021-05-06 16:02:37
 3,   4,        4514,               C,         2021-04-05 10:55:18
 4,   4,        4560,               D,         2021-04-10 11:56:18
 5,   5,        6899,               Y,         2021-04-07 09:53:45
 6,   2,        7891,               A,         2021-04-07 09:59:21
 7,   2,        8120,               B,         2021-06-04 09:19:41
 8,   3,        9423,               Z,         2021-03-28 15:34:29
 9,   3,        9423,               X,         2021-03-28 15:34:29
           ...            ...              ....
```

I want to get which product led to another for each customer and than calculate the interval between pairs, for example:
customer 1 bought product A in his first order then product B in his second one. So product A led to product B (A->B) that's a pair. And then calculate the average intervals.

I need your help to find the best approach in order to achieve what I already explained and the best way to display the output in order to calculate the average interval between those pairs and a library to visualise it.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result= pd.DataFrame()
df.purchase_at = pd.to_datetime(df.purchase_at)
df = df.sort_values(by='purchase_at')
unique_customers = df.customer_id.unique()
result = pd.DataFrame()
for customer in unique_customers:
    temp = df[df.customer_id == customer].copy()
    if len(temp) > 1:
        temp['previous_sale'] = temp['product'].shift()
        temp['previous_order_id'] = temp['order_id'].shift()
        temp['previous_sale_date'] = temp['purchase_at'].shift()
        temp['time_diff'] = temp.purchase_at.diff()
        result = result.append(temp[1:])
```

Comment: Is there a way to put previous_sale_date and order_id?

Comment: I changed the code in response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, but there's one more thing which is that the same order_id is repeating between current and previous purchase which results time diff = 0 days 00:00:00

Comment: It is not repeating in my code. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that I don't want product from the same order_id to be in the same row, like if product A was bought in order 1 by customer 2  and product b and c were bought in order 2 by the same customer. So customer 2 product b, previous sale product a. and customer 2 product c previous sale product a.

Comment: It is hard to visualise unless you can show what output you want. However, I think I have answered the original question.